# Which object is better for creating a curve using b2EdgeShape vs b2ChainShape?

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode, box2d

I have a function that generates points for a curve. I use these points the create the box2d body representing the ground.

I have tried the following two ways of doing this:

1. Generate all the points and store them in an array. The create fixtures between any two consecutive points edge shapes.
2. Generate all the points and store them in an array. Create a b2ChainShape, and create the fixture for the chain shape.

When testing, both the curves look equally smooth (they use the same points after all). According to the time profiler instrument in Xcode, the methods I use to generate the body take approximately the same amount of running time (almost down to the millisecond).

Any reason why I should pick one over the other ?

Comment: Your statement: "The create fixtures between any two consecutive points edge shapes."  Do you mean: "Then create fixtures between any two consecutive points using b2EdgeShape(s)."

Comment: b2ChainShape uses b2EdgeShape internally, so there is no difference in performance. A chain shape is easier to set up because it arranges the ghost vertices for you, that's about the only difference.

Comment: Yes, Nonlinearideas, I meant create using b2EdgeShapes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual:

> Chain Shapes
>
> The chain shape provides an efficient way to connect many edges
>   together to construct your static game worlds. Chain shapes
>   automatically eliminate ghost collisions and provide two-sided
>   collision.

From the title of your question, you are looking at creating a long series of individual edges vs. creating a single chain shape.  The chain shape is more efficient for doing the creation of "lots of edges".

From an implementation standpoint, I can't say whether or not there is a performance difference for collision detection (my guess is no because you are still looking for the collisions between the individual edges).